# AWS: Deploy Container with execution command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I created locally a docker Image and deployed several container from the Image with an execution command (on deployement). I uploaded the Image to AWS ECR and build a ECS cluster. After that i am a little bit lost. I think i have to create Tasks but i found no option to set an execution command (for example a PowerShell command) and the documentation is a mess (my optionion). Tips?

BR
Timo

Answer (score 0):

Please use this tutorial [1] and in Step 2 change the image from 'httpd' to your own image in ECR.

Also make sure to refer the image URI correctly from ECR, please check [2] for correct syntax.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/

[2] Using Amazon ECR Images with Amazon ECS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_on_ECS.html